# IntelliJ IDE: How to disable Markdown Styling toolbar on cursor in markdown

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

When I write Markdown in PyCharm/IntelliJ, it shows this toolbar just over my cursor and hides the text behind it. So if I'm selecting a text to delete, I can't see what I'm deleting. How do I disable this?

[image]

Comment: Normally the formatting toolbar shouldn't overlap the content on selection. It should appear above the selected line. Try using the 2021.3 EAP version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion .

Comment: If the problem remains raise a new issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA , and provide the IDE logs to collect more information about your work environment. `Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data`